# WebRTC using React: Why the remote video is not playing?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I have two services, one is sending video service and the other is receiving video service.
The server only forwards the information and forwards the information to the other party.
The service that receives the video can receive the video at some times, but most of them cannot.
I don't know where the problem occurred, the service that sends the video or the service that receives the video.

caller

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

function createPeerConnection() {
    const myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
    return myPeerConnection;
}

async function setLocalStream(myPeerConnection, target) {
    console.log("setLocalStream");
    const webcamStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
    });
    target.srcObject = webcamStream;
    webcamStream
        .getTracks()
        .forEach((track) =>
            myPeerConnection.addTransceiver(track, { streams: [webcamStream] })
        );
}

const App = () => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [socket] = useState(io());
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit("init", "hello");
        socket.on("init", (res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }, []);
    const handleNegotiationNeededEvent = useCallback(
        (myPeerConnection) => async () => {
            try {
                const offer = await myPeerConnection.createOffer();
                await myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
                console.log(
                    "send video-offer",
                    myPeerConnection.localDescription
                );
                socket.emit("video-offer", myPeerConnection.localDescription);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        },
        [socket]
    );
    const handleICECandidateEvent = useCallback(
        (event) => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                console.log("send new-ice-candidate", event.candidate);
                socket.emit("new-ice-candidate", event.candidate);
            }
        },
        [socket]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const myPeerConnection = createPeerConnection();
        myPeerConnection.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent;
        myPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = handleNegotiationNeededEvent(
            myPeerConnection
        );
        setLocalStream(myPeerConnection, ref.current);
        socket.on("video-answer", async (sdp) => {
            console.log("received video-answer", sdp);
            const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(sdp);
            try {
                await myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(desc);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
        socket.on("new-ice-candidate", async (c) => {
            console.log("received new-ice-candidate", c);
            const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(c);
            try {
                await myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            <video style={{ width: "10px" }} ref={ref} autoPlay muted />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

callee

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

function createPeerConnection() {
    const myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
    return myPeerConnection;
}

const App = () => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [socket] = useState(io());
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit("init", "hello");
        socket.on("init", (res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }, []);

    const handleICECandidateEvent = useCallback(
        (event) => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                console.log("send new-ice-candidate", event.candidate);
                socket.emit("new-ice-candidate", event.candidate);
            }
        },
        [socket]
    );

    const handleTrackEvent = useCallback((event) => {
        ref.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const myPeerConnection = createPeerConnection();
        myPeerConnection.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent;
        myPeerConnection.ontrack = handleTrackEvent;
        socket.on("video-offer", async (sdp) => {
            console.log("received offer", sdp);
            const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(sdp);
            await myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(desc);
            await myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(
                await myPeerConnection.createAnswer()
            );
            console.log("send answer", myPeerConnection.localDescription);
            socket.emit("video-answer", myPeerConnection.localDescription);
        });
        socket.on("new-ice-candidate", async (c) => {
            console.log("received new-ice-candidate", c);
            const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(c);
            try {
                await myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            <video style={{ width: "20px" }} ref={ref} autoPlay />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't use react, but have you tried adding STUN and TURN servers?

Comment: is there any free STUN or TURN servers

Comment: [webRTC stun / turn server list · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/sagivo/3a4b2f2c7ac6e1b5267c2f1f59ac6c6b) I can't verify the validity of any of them, but I use `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` and my own TURN server.